# anaconda/lib/libcurl.so.4 no version information available when i compile opencv at ubuntu14

Tags: opencv, cmake, libcurl, anaconda

When I compiled opencv on Ubuntu, I met this problem
"/usr/bin/cmake: /usr/home/anaconda/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by cmake)".

I don't know the reason, I have found libcurl.so.4 at /usr/home/anaconda/lib/,  is it because I have other version of libcurl.so.4? or I should reinstall the anaconda?

Answer (score 2):

Removing conda curl didn't help me. I had to upgrade cmake and curl:

```
conda upgrade curl
conda upgrade cmake
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `conda remove curl` and compile against the system curl.

Answer (score 0):

How about add "su" before the command?

Comment: you can add this in comment.